# Trouble viewing Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, proxy

I'm behind a firewall and all of a sudden, I'm unable to access Stack Exchange sites. I checked with the IT team and here is what they had to say:

> We have analyzed the site: stackoverflow.com. There is no blockage in the proxy level. Analysis revealed that browsing traffic was reaching the stackoverflow.com domain but there was no reverse traffic coming back from the domain. We suspect that the public IP addresses of proxy servers might be blocked in their premises which has to be taken up with the stackoverflow IT team for releasing the same.

Any clues?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing me to that post. I'll touch base with the user and we'll take it from there. So we could close this question?

Answer (score 1):

I've written to the SO team and they have got back to me saying that the IP address cannot be unblocked. I've replied back asking if something can be done from my end to stop the malicious user.